# Cucumber - And I should see "first" before "last" - Rails 3.1

Tags: testing, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1, integration-testing

[Note: Using Rails 3.1.]

I am trying to test that multiple models are being displayed in the proper order on my page, in my case, by desc date with the most recent on top.

I know I can do the following to check if something exists on the page:

```
And I should see "Some content on my page."
```

But I want to do something along the lines of:

```
And I should see "Most Recent" before "Really old"
```

How would I go about writing steps to do that? I believe "And I should see" just scans the entire page for the specified argument, just not sure how to approach correct order.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001142) on page.body to find the position of each, and assert first < second, e.g.

```
And /^I should see "([^"]*)" before "([^"]*)"$/ do |phrase_1, phrase_2|
  first_position = page.body.index(phrase_1)
  second_position = page.body.index(phrase_2)
  first_position.should < second_position
end
```

Comment: Can you possibly clarify a bit more with this?

Answer (score 0):

A more flat version, with MiniTest assertion:

```
And /^I should see "([^"]*)" before "([^"]*)"$/ do |phrase_1, phrase_2|
  assert page.body.index(phrase_1) < page.body.index(phrase_2)
end
```